# Angular 7: Service not updating the page dynamically, Its getting updated after reloading the page

Tags: angular

I am working in `angular 7` I have to perform simple task there is one component `teacher-details` which shows the list of registered teacher in a table format (Getting this from database using node js) and also update the table when new teacher record is added, I also have a `teacher.service.ts` which contain teacher array and contain a method `getTeacher()` and `addTeacher()` so teacher component using this service to display the record.

**My problem is when I enter new record of teacher its not getting update to the UI/page but when I reload the it gets updated, But I want to update the page dynamically as soon as I enter the record.**

**teacher-details.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-teacher-details',
  templateUrl: './teacher-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teacher-details.component.css']
})
export class TeacherDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  private teachers: Teacher[] = []
  constructor(private teacherServ: TeachersService, private auth: AuthService) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.auth.getTeacherRecords().subscribe(
      res => this.teachers = res.message,
      err => console.log(err)
    ),



    this.teachers = this.teacherServ.getTeachers();
  }

}
```

**teacher.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class TeachersService {
teacherChanged = new EventEmitter<Teacher[]>();
private teachers: Teacher[] = [];

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  getTeachers() {
    return this.teachers;
  }

  addTeachers(teacher: any) {
    this.auth.addTeacher(teacher)
    .subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
      err => console.log(err)
    );
    this.teachers.push(teacher);
  }
}
```

I am also sharing my auth service which gets the details from the database.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private addTeacherUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/addTeacher"
  private getTeacherRecordsUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/getTeacherRecords"

  addTeacher(teacherRecord: any) {
    console.log("Inside addTEacher servvice")
    console.log(teacherRecord)
    return this.http.post<any>(this.addTeacherUrl, teacherRecord)
  }

  getTeacherRecords() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.getTeacherRecordsUrl, {
     observe: "body" 
    })
  }
}
```

**teacher-details.component.html**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header border-0">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col">
        <h3 class="mb-0">Teacher Details</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <!-- Projects table -->
    <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Teacher Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Teacher subject</th>
          <th scope="col">Teacher branch</th>
          <th scope="col">Teacher Semester</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let teachers of teachers">
          <th scope="row">
            {{teachers.fullName}}
          </th>
          <td>
            {{teachers.subject}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{teachers.branch}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{teachers.semester}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am very confused what should I do, Please help me out here.

**UPDATE:-**

I did the following changes according to the suggestion:

**auth.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private addTeacherUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/addTeacher"
  private getTeacherRecordsUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/getTeacherRecords"

   subject = new Subject<Teacher[]>();
   teachers: Teacher[] 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addTeacher(teacherRecord: any) {

    console.log("Inside addTEacher servvice")
    console.log(teacherRecord)
    this.teachers.push(teacherRecord)
    this.subject.next(this.teachers)
    return this.http.post<any>(this.addTeacherUrl, teacherRecord)
  }

  getTeacherRecords() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.getTeacherRecordsUrl, {
     observe: "body" 
    })
  }
}
```

**teacher-details.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-teacher-details',
  templateUrl: './teacher-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teacher-details.component.css']
})
export class TeacherDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

   teachers: Teacher[];
  constructor(private teacherServ: TeachersService, private auth: AuthService) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.getTeacherRecords().subscribe(
      res => this.teachers = res.message,
      err => console.log(err)
    );


    this.auth.subject.subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
      err => console.log(err)
    )
  }

}
```

**Still data getting updated after reloading the page**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getTeachers()` method in your service is synchronous and will return values only when it is called.

What you probably need is a `Subject` that emits values whenever you tell it to.
I believe something like this in your service:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new Subject<Teacher[]>();

addTeacher(teacherRecord: any) {
    console.log("Inside addTEacher servvice")
    console.log(teacherRecord)
    //HERE YOU ADD THIS
    this.teachers.add(teacherRecord);
    this.subject.next(this.teachers);

    return this.http.post<any>(this.addTeacherUrl, teacherRecord)
}
```

and in your ts file you initialize like this:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.auth.getTeacherRecords().subscribe(
      res => this.teachers = res.message,
      err => console.log(err)
    ),

    this.auth.subject.subscribe(
      res => this.teachers = res.message,
      err => console.log(err)
    ),
  }
```

Also, remember to unsubscribe on `OnDestroy` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Sen Alexandru thanks for replying, It updates the values but removes the old data that already present in the page.

Comment: @AyushVerma I've updated my answer. Please check the updated `addTeacher()` method

Comment: I did work, I updated my new code please check it. Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: @AyushVerma I believe the error is generated by the fact that the `teachers` variable is not initialized.
I would change that line with `teachers: Teacher[] = []`

Comment: I did error is gone but still, data getting updated after refresh, I know you tried very hard but still its not working please tell me what else I can do ?

Comment: @AyushVerma Tell me exactly what happens.
1. The teacher list is returned from the API?
2. The add works?
3. Is there a problem after adding a new teacher?

Comment: @AyushVerma, You only log the subject data so change

`this.auth.subject.subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
      err => console.log(err)
    )`

to this

`this.auth.subject.subscribe(
      res => this.teachers = res,
      err => console.log(err)
    )`

Comment: Yes, I have teacher-dashboard which contain a button addteacher on click matdialog opens i enter the details when I press enter New teacher gets updated to the database successfully but not getting updated in to UI/page but when I refresh the page It Get updated.....Is there any way In which I share my whole code with you ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply

[https://stackblitz.com/github/ayush-ashu/student_management?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadmin-dashboard%2Fteacher-details%2Fteacher-details.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/github/ayush-ashu/student_management?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadmin-dashboard%2Fteacher-details%2Fteacher-details.component.ts)

Comment: did you check the link ?

Comment: @AyushVerma yes, but there are a lot of problems. First, the example is not working, as you probably saw, it has errors when you try to run it on stackblitz. The urls should be in the ```environment.ts``` file, not in auth service. All teacher related logic should be in the teacher service, not in auth, etc. So, my advice is to try to clean up and organize the code. Place some breakpoints or console.log in order to see what happens

Answer (score 1):

You subscribe to the `getTeacherRecords()` in `onInit()`.

This method returns an observable which is not getting updated when you do something on the page because a new HTTP request is not send.

The issue is that you use an observable that does not emit other values.
As I can see, you use `EventEmitter` in teachers service. 
You should subscribe to it in your component like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.teachers = this.teacherServ.teacherChanged.subscribe(
        teachers => this.teachers = teachers
    );
  }
```

*Note* You should `unsubscribe` in `ngOnDestroy` - it's best practice.

Do not forget to emit teachers after addition:

```js
addTeachers(teacher: any) {
    this.auth.addTeacher(teacher)
    .subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
      err => console.log(err)
    );
    this.teachers.push(teacher);
    // note that line
    this.teacherChanged.emit(this.teachers);
  }
```

This should work, hope that hepls!